# Is there a way to replace redis storage with cookies?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, redis, mern

I'm trying to store JWT in redis, but heroku is asking way too much for single connection.

So I thought of replacing the redis with cookies (if possible)

Here is my redis code:

```
const redis = require("redis");
const client = redis.createClient(process.env.REDIS_URL);

const setJWT = (key, value) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            client.set(key, value, (error, response) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^");
                    console.log(error);
                    reject(error);
                }
                resolve(response);
            });
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
        }
    });
};

const getJWT = (key) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            client.get(key, (error, response) => {
                if (error) reject(error);
                resolve(response);
            });
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
        }
    });
};

const deleteJWT = (key) => {
    try {
        client.del(key);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};

module.exports = {
    setJWT,
    getJWT,
    deleteJWT,
};
```

**Can someone tell me if it is possible? If so, any hints?**

Comment: A bit low on detail here. For starters, using cookies in any way requires some cooperation between the client and the server, so what is the client calling the API?

Comment: I'm using to store the jwt created by the jwt sign method... I ask someone who told me to store it on MongoDB so is it a correct way?